# How to call function JavaScript when popup dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` tag:

```
<select id="categoryID" onchange="changeCategory(this)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%">
  @foreach($category as $item)                                            
    <option id="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>;
  @endforeach
</select>
<script>
    function initialSelect() {
        $(".select2").select2();
    }
    $(function () {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $(".select2").select2();
    });
</script>
```

This code will show: [image]

Then I put it into dialog when this dialog will popup when clicking on button:

```
<button onclick="typeAdd()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#addNewCategoryModal">New
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="addNewCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleLabel">New Category</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
         <select id="categoryID" onchange="changeCategory(this)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%">
           @foreach($category as $item)                                            
             <option id="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>;
           @endforeach
        </select>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
    function initialSelect() {
        $(".select2").select2();
    }
    $(function () {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $(".select2").select2();
    });
</script>
```

But when dialog popup, `select` tag will show but cant type in it (search in `input` tag).
[image]

I think cause is `$(".select2").select2();`, so I try to set this line when dialog shown by:

```
$('#addNewCategoryModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var modal = $(this)
        initialSelect();
        modal.find('.modal-body #category_id').val(categoryID)
        modal.find('.modal-body #type').val(type)
        //this
        modal.find('.modal-body #categoryID').select2();
        modal.find('.modal-body categoryID').select2();
        modal.find('.select2').select2();
        $(".select2").select2();
    })
```

It not working, please helps. Thanks.

Comment: Make a working copy of your code here, it helps with debugging. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I make another question with code, please take a look :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894154/select2-jquery-in-popup