# Select2 jquery plugin in popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `select` tag implement `select2 jquery plugin`:

- `select` tag normal: working fine, can search.
- `select` tag in popup: cant search.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/select2/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/demo.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="categoryID" onchange="changeCategory(this)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%">
        <option id="1">Games</option>
        <option id="2">Sport</option>
        <option id="3">Sport Games</option>
    </select>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/demo.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#addNewCategoryModal">New
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="addNewCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleLabel">New Category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="categoryID" onchange="changeCategory(this)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%">
                            <option id="1">Games</option>
                            <option id="2">Sport</option>
                            <option id="3">Sport Games</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialSelect() {
            $(".select2").select2();
        }
        $(function () {
            //Initialize Select2 Elements
            $(".select2").select2();
        });
        $('#addNewCategoryModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var modal = $(this)
            modal.find('.modal-body #categoryID').select2();
            modal.find('.modal-body categoryID').select2();
            modal.find('.select2').select2();
            $(".select2").select2();
        })
    </script>

</div>
</body>
```

Any helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `tabindex="-1"` for the modal. Because of this input is not getting focussed. Remove tabindex from your code and it should work.

Also there are following issues in your code

- you have included bootstrap and select2 js files multiple times your HTML. Include only once.
- Include your jquery file before including bootstrap js file.
- You are using `categoryID` multiple times your HTML page. IDs has to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This Works for me

```
    <script>
        $('#mySelect2').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
        });
    </script>
```

Source from:

[Select2 web](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems)

Comment: You are right, I just edited the post, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From everyone who search an answer when you use select2 + [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) extension.
The come around solution is to alter the style of the dropdown container, inside the event 'select2:open'.

```
$('select[name=extension]').on('select2:open', ()=>{
    $('.select2-container').css('z-index', 99999999);
})
```